# NSNotification not received

Tags: ios, objective-c, multithreading

I have a multithreaded program sending messages through NSNotificationCenter (addObserver:.. and postNotification:... methods).

The threads are subscribed for different notifications, some of them shared, so that a message should be received in various threads.

Normally, all the notifications are properly received and processed in all the threads, but sometimes the callback function of the notification is not invoked in some of the threads that are listening for the notification.

Is there a way of assure that all my notifications will be processed by all the subscribed threads?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What matters isn't the thread on which you subscribe to the notification, but the thread on which the notification is posted. You'd probably have to write your own notification manager to make this happen. I don't think it would be overly complicated, and I would recommend to use `dispatch_queue_t`s rather than threads.

Comment: Sorry, but I don´t understand . All the notifications are posted in the same thread. Why are some received and others not?

Comment: If you provide some of the code you're using it might be easier to help you identify where you've gone wrong.

Comment: Just solved! Reviewing my code I realized the notifications were working properly. The problem was a parameter of an operation with NSPort performed in the listener of the notification observer. Thanks for the collaboration!

Answer (score 0):

NSNotificationCenter launch the registered mehod on the same thread where the original notification has fired. Are you sure that this thread is still alive?